# Can't unwrap Optional on popViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, swift

I know the error `Can't unwrap optional` means that somewhere the program is trying to unwrap a nil variable. Trouble is I can't figure out where.

I'm writing up an edit screen that presents modally. The user changes stuff, it's saved and we pop back to the 'detail' screen which shows the updated object.

I'm on my 2nd VC, I've breakpoints all over the place and the crash is triggered on the line

```
self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

I've got breakpoints in the VC I'm returning to and no code is being run, so I can't understand which optional the program is trying to unwrap.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Does it have something to do with the VC I'm returning to being dealloced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And also, your original issue is that `self.navigationController` is `nil`, so you crash trying to access it. If you presented modally, you could also dismiss like this:

```
self.presentingViewController.dismissViewController(true)
```

To make it always work, you can do:

```
if self.navigationController {
    self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
else if self.presentingViewController {
    self.presentingViewController.dismissViewController(true)
}
else {
    // Unknown presentation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let segueLabel = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LabelViewController") as! LabelViewController
    let segueGeluid = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SoundViewController") as! SoundViewController

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(segueLabel, animated: true)
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(segueGeluid, animated: true)
    }
```

While using the pushViewController on the navigationController, the navigationController pushes the new ViewController. Navigation will be present. I think this is the best solution.
With the following code, you could easily go back to the previous ViewController:

```
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was used the wrong method to dismiss the controller. It was modally presented, so it didn't respond to `popViewControllerAnimated` - I needed to implement a protocol and delegate pattern so that the main VC could dismiss it.

Comment: You could also do `self.presentingViewController dismissViewController:`